# Verify that a point is inside a lattice

Tags: lattice-crypto

I am wondering if there's a polynomial time algorithm that, given a lattice $\Lambda$ with basis $\mathbf{B}$ and a point $x$ in space, it tells you whether $x$ is in $\Lambda$ or not!

Answer (score 3):

If you compute a base of a the dual lattice, and then check that the inner product of the point and the vector if this base are all integers:
To compute this base it's $\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{B}^{T}\mathbf{B})^{-1}$:

https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse206A-a/LecDual.pdf

Comment: But if the lattice is full-rank, no vector will be perpendicular to all the basis vectors... Maybe do you mean to check if the inner products are integral?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Can one simply check if the solution $\alpha$ to the system
$$
\mathbf{B}\cdot\alpha^\top = [\mathbf{b}_1,\dots, \mathbf{b}_k]\cdot (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k)^\top=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \mathbf{b}_i=\mathbf{x}
$$
lies in $\mathbb{Z}^k$, i.e. if $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$?

Comment: How do you do this? remember $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field.

Comment: you solve over $\mathbb{R}$ and check if the solution you obtain is in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: by linear independence of $(\mathbf{b}_1,\dots,\mathbf{b}_k)$, there exists unique $(\alpha_i)_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i\mathbf{b}_i=\mathbf{x}$ (over $\mathbb{R}$). If such $\alpha_i$'s are all integers, then $\mathbf{x}$ is a point of the lattice. Otherwise not.

Comment: Then you have to intersect your solution set with $\mathbb{Z}^k$. Feasible, but not simple: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347221/intersection-of-a-mathbbq-affine-space-with-mathbbzn/347229#347229

Comment: I think one has to just check if the $\alpha_i$'s obtained are integers or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your solution is not a unique vector. In the general case, it's an affine space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112205/discussion-between-asd-and-ievgeni).

Comment: After discussion. It seems that asd is right. And I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

There's a relatively simple one by using Hermite Normal Form computations.
Essentially, if $\mathbf{B} = [b_1,\dots, b_k]$, then you check if:
$$\mathsf{HNF}([b_1,\dots,b_k]) = \mathsf{HNF}([b_1,\dots,b_k, x])$$
This generalizes to the case of checking if a lattice $\mathcal{L}(A)$ is a sub-lattice of $\mathcal{L}(B)$ --- just check if $\mathsf{HNF}(B) = \mathsf{HNF}(B\cup A)$, where $B \cup A$ is the "union" of all the basis vectors.

The HNF can be used to solve a variety of "algebraic" problems on lattices, see for example [section 4 of these notes](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse206A-a/lec2.pdf). In general "algebraic" problems on lattices are easy (usually via the HNF), while "geometric" ones are hard. Ajtai has actually written a paper formulating this via an explicit conjecture (see [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1007352.1007426), which is an extension of his initial conjecture).